# Сервер на windows

Tags: windows-7, сервер

Здравствуйте. Подскажите какую-нибудь тему, где полностью описано, как установить сервер на windows, с подключением dns и вообще, чтобы работал, как на обычном хостинге.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так: http://habrahabr.ru/post/150972/

Answer (score 0):

Если что это статья хорошая http://habrahabr.ru/post/127090/